# Trying to convert the date of a column to be mmddyyyy when it is yyyymmdd while in a table with other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having an issue trying to convert the dates of a column to be a standard MMDDYYYY format.

For example I have a table with data as follows:

```
ID   |   Date   |   Type   |
----------------------------
1    | 20140308 | License  |
2    | 20140308 | License  |
3    | 48       | License  |
```

The outcome I want to receive is:

```
ID   |   Date      |   Type   |
-------------------------------
1    | 3-8-2014    | License  |
2    | 3-8-2014    | License  |
3    | 48(not sure)| License  |
```

Is this possible when I have garbage data going into the system? I keep getting an error like this when I try to convert the dates into MMDDYYYY.

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string. Warning: Null value is
>   eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Comment: Can you post the SQL script that is attempting to do the conversion?

Comment: select distinct ID, convert(varchar(10),convert(date,DATECOLUMN),101)

Comment: @JaronCook have a look at my solution I have used `ISDATE()` function which returns 1 if the passed parameter value is a date value and 0 if its not. Since you have mentioned you may have some garbage data in your column, I think this is the safest way to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this....

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(ID INT,[Date] VARCHAR(8),[Type] VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
(1,'20140308','License'),
(2,'20140307','License'),
(3,'48'      ,'License')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT ID 
      ,CASE WHEN ISDATE([Date]) = 1
                THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST([DATE] AS DATE), 110)
            ELSE NULL END AS [Date]
      ,[Type]
FROM @Table
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════╗
║ ID ║    Date    ║  Type   ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════╣
║  1 ║ 03-08-2014 ║ License ║
║  2 ║ 03-07-2014 ║ License ║
║  3 ║ NULL       ║ License ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: Note that if your `Date` column is an `int` data type then you will need to cast as a `varchar`  prior to converting to a date, or you will get and error "Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed".  Example: `THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[DATE]) AS DATE), 110)`

Comment: @BateTech this is not correct I have used the `ISDATE()` function in case statement and it will only try to convert it to DATE if it is a date value otherwise it will simply return null, I was going to create a sql fiddle to prove this but it seems to be down, try it yourself :)

Comment: you are correct in stating that the `ISDATE` function works with an `int`, and will return true for an int of 20140308, but I was talking about the `CONVERT` or `CAST` from int to date.  Try this and you'll see what error I'm referring to `DECLARE @date int; SET @date = 20140308; select CASE WHEN ISDATE(@date) = 1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(@date AS DATE), 110) ELSE NULL END;`, which will give an error, but this will work: `DECLARE @date int; SET @date = 20140308; select CASE WHEN ISDATE(@date) = 1 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @date) AS DATE), 110) ELSE NULL END;`

Comment: Also `IsDate` will return true if the 4 digit year is the only value. If you do not want to treat a 4 digit year as a valid date since you expect YYYYMMDD format, then you can change `WHEN ISDATE([Date]) = 1`  to  `WHEN ISDATE([Date]) = 1 AND LEN([Date]) = 8` to only accept YYYYMMDD format as valid.  Otherwise, casting a 4 digit year to a date will assume Jan 01 as the month and day.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I ended up using 'CASE WHEN ISDATE([DATE])=1 THEN CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST([DATE] AS DATE), 101) AS DATE) ELSE NULL END AS Exp_Date' in order to convert it back into a date and use that for filtering properly into excel spreadsheets when it is exported.

Comment: glad you found the solution if the answer helped you please accept it thank you.

Comment: @M.Ali How come my inline text formatting isn't working with my comment?

Comment: you need to use i think its called tilted single quote ` around your text.

Comment: Like this? `CASE WHEN ISDATE([DATE])=1 THEN CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST([DATE] AS DATE), 101) AS DATE) ELSE NULL END AS Exp_Date`

Comment: Thank you. I'm still new to SO :D I appreciate your help.