# Updating string values in a table to be flopped around such as YYYYMMDD string to MMDDYYYY string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table setup for example as

CREATE TABLE Test_Table
(
ID int,
DATES varchar(8)
);

and my table looks like this when selecting it

```
|   ID    |    Dates   |
------------------------
|    1    |  20140911  |
|    2    |  20140101  |
|    3    |  20140829  |
```

I'm trying to update my table so that the string value is MMDDYYYY instead of YYYYMMDD
For example this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
|   ID    |    Dates   |
------------------------
|    1    |  09112014  |
|    2    |  01012014  |
|    3    |  08292014  |
```

*NOTE:* I'm not trying to select the table or change the value into datetime. All I'm trying to do is flop the numbers around and update my table if that is even possible.

Comment: I suggest at first to change the scheme of your table and make the field `Dates` of type `date`.

Comment: If you always treat dates as dates, you'll avoid surprising other developers later.

Comment: So I can't change the string values around like that without using date types? Because I really don't want to use date types.

Comment: @JaronCook Yes you can do that, but that is not a **good practice**

Comment: @abhi I realize that, but it's what I'm trying to accomplish. I know that having the values be under date types would make selecting easier, but I want to maintain the string value and have it changed to look like MMDDYYYY.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to convert the date of a column to be mmddyyyy when it is yyyymmdd while in a table with other columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22974161/trying-to-convert-the-date-of-a-column-to-be-mmddyyyy-when-it-is-yyyymmdd-while)

Comment: Please don't open duplicates of your own question.

Comment: @dodexahedron I realize that I reposted and I flagged my old post to be removed to prevent any confusion prior to your comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming our date column is `char` or `varchar`, you could do something like this

```
update foo
set dates = right(dates,4) + left(dates,4)
```

Or this

```
update foo
set dates = replace( convert(varchar,convert(datetime,dates,112),110) , '-' , '' )
```

If all you want to do is *display* your text differently, the easiest way is

```
select ... ,
       dates = right(dates,4) + left(dates,4)
from foo
```

Or create a view and use that instead of the original table:

```
create view foo_view
as select id ,
          dates = right(dates,4) + left(dates,4)
   from foo
```

But if you use actual date/time data types, users of your data will get them mapped to suitable date/time types in the client and can then choose how best to display them for their needs.

The other advantage of using date/time types is that they enforce *data integrity*. Wait until somebody adds or changes a date to make it invalid — say, `20142331'. Then, when you need to display that data in a form with a month name ('Jan 22, 2014, say), hilarity will ensue when you get an exception trying to map the month number to a month name.

If you're not going to use a date/time type, then store year, month and day individually as integer values with suitable check constraints to enforce integrity:

```
create table foo
(
  id   int not null identity(1,1) primary key ,
  yyyy int not null check ( yyyy between 1900 and 2100 ) ,
  mm   int not null check ( mm between 1 and 12 ) ,
  dd   int not null check ( dd between 1 and ( case mm
                                                 when  4 then 30
                                                 when  6 then 30
                                                 when  9 then 30
                                                 when 11 then 30
                                                 when  2 then case
                                                                when yyyy % 400 = 0 then 29
                                                                when yyyy % 100 = 0 then 28
                                                                when yyyy % 4   = 0 then 29
                                                                else                     28
                                                              end
                                                 else 31
                                               end
                                             )
                          )
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way would be to convert the string to a date, and then back out in the desired format within an update statement.

Unfortunately I cannot run any code at this time, so any example code I could give would probably be unhelpful, but hopefully these links will assist you. It may be necessary to perform direct string manipulation as I notice that sql server 2008 appears to lack a "date mask" style of conversion.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878(v=sql.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Note that this is the EXACT reason you would typically store a date as a date object. It's quite straight forward to create an output string from a date in a format you desire in a select statement, but more convoluted to do so when it is stored as raw characters.

Sorry this answer isn't better; my primary experience is in Oracle, but hopefully this gets you started.

Comment: As a matter of fact, you could simply transform the integer into a string and then rearrange the string in the OP's case.